# jest + enzyme + react16: <img> src : request not sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using jest + enzyme to test my react component "AnimateImage" which contains an image element:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { PureComponent } from 'react';

interface Props {
    src: string;
}

class AnimateImage extends PureComponent<Props> {

    onImgLoad = (e: Event | {target: HTMLImageElement}) => {
        console.log("yes!");
    };
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="app-image-container">
                    <img
                        ref={c => {
                            if (!c) {
                                return;
                            }
                            c.onerror = function(e){
                                console.log("error:" , e);
                            }
                            if(!c.onload){
                                c.onload = this.onImgLoad;
                                if (c && c.complete && c.naturalWidth !== 0) {
                                    this.onImgLoad({
                                        target: c
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }}
                        src={this.props.src}
                    />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
export default AnimateImage;
```

test code:

```
test("image ", () => {
    const component = mount(<AnimateImage src={url_test}/>);

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();

    console.log("end ##################################################################");
})
```

the expected result:

the image's onload handler is called and I can see the "yes!" printed in the console.

the real result:

the image's onload handler is not called and the image's complete attribute is false.

my jest configuration:

```
    verbose: true,
    transform: {
        '.(ts|tsx)': 'ts-jest'
    },
    snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'json'],
    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    testEnvironmentOptions: { "resources": 'usable' },
```

debug step:

1. I've confirmed that the Canvas is installed successfully and works well in the jsdom.
2. the jsdom's resource-loader uses "request-promise-native" package to fetch HTTP resource. The "request-promise-native" package's core is "request" package.

in the "request" package, the request.js file declares a class called Request to handle HTTP request.

But I found that the Request.start() function is never called and the defer function is called with the request's status "abort".

by the way, I've put two "console.log()" in the function where the simulated "window" and "document" call "close" function and "console.log('abort')" in the place where the request is handled.

3. the result shows that the jsdom "window" is closed before the real HTTP request starts outgoing and then, this request's status is set to be "abort".

```
bogon:  yarn test:dom
yarn run v1.10.1
$ jest --config jest.config.js
 PASS  animate-image.spec.tsx
  ✓ image (75ms)

  console.log xxxxxxxxx/animate-image.spec.tsx:34
    end ##################################################################

window close
document close
http://XXXXX.cdn.com
abort
```

some piece of code in the request.js, may be helpful to understand the problem:

```
var defer = typeof setImmediate === 'undefined'
  ? process.nextTick
  : setImmediate
```

```
 defer(function () {
    if (self._aborted) {
      return
    }

    var end = function () {
      if (self._form) {
        if (!self._auth.hasAuth) {
          self._form.pipe(self)
        } else if (self._auth.hasAuth && self._auth.sentAuth) {
          self._form.pipe(self)
        }
      }
      if (self._multipart && self._multipart.chunked) {
        self._multipart.body.pipe(self)
      }
      if (self.body) {
        if (isstream(self.body)) {
          self.body.pipe(self)
        } else {
          setContentLength()
          if (Array.isArray(self.body)) {
            self.body.forEach(function (part) {
              self.write(part)
            })
          } else {
            self.write(self.body)
          }
          self.end()
        }
      } else if (self.requestBodyStream) {
        console.warn('options.requestBodyStream is deprecated, please pass the request object to stream.pipe.')
        self.requestBodyStream.pipe(self)
      } else if (!self.src) {
        if (self._auth.hasAuth && !self._auth.sentAuth) {
          self.end()
          return
        }
        if (self.method !== 'GET' && typeof self.method !== 'undefined') {
          self.setHeader('content-length', 0)
        }
        self.end()
      }
    }

    if (self._form && !self.hasHeader('content-length')) {
      // Before ending the request, we had to compute the length of the whole form, asyncly
      self.setHeader(self._form.getHeaders(), true)
      self._form.getLength(function (err, length) {
        if (!err && !isNaN(length)) {
          self.setHeader('content-length', length)
        }
        end()
      })
    } else {
      end()
    }

    self.ntick = true
  })
```

```
Request.prototype.start = function () {
  // start() is called once we are ready to send the outgoing HTTP request.
  // this is usually called on the first write(), end() or on nextTick()
  var self = this

  if (self.timing) {
    // All timings will be relative to this request's startTime.  In order to do this,
    // we need to capture the wall-clock start time (via Date), immediately followed
    // by the high-resolution timer (via now()).  While these two won't be set
    // at the _exact_ same time, they should be close enough to be able to calculate
    // high-resolution, monotonically non-decreasing timestamps relative to startTime.
    var startTime = new Date().getTime()
    var startTimeNow = now()
  }

  if (self._aborted) {
    return
  }

  self._started = true
  self.method = self.method || 'GET'
  self.href = self.uri.href

  if (self.src && self.src.stat && self.src.stat.size && !self.hasHeader('content-length')) {
    self.setHeader('content-length', self.src.stat.size)
  }
  if (self._aws) {
    self.aws(self._aws, true)
  }

  // We have a method named auth, which is completely different from the http.request
  // auth option.  If we don't remove it, we're gonna have a bad time.
  var reqOptions = copy(self)
  delete reqOptions.auth

  debug('make request', self.uri.href)

  // node v6.8.0 now supports a `timeout` value in `http.request()`, but we
  // should delete it for now since we handle timeouts manually for better
  // consistency with node versions before v6.8.0
  delete reqOptions.timeout

  try {
    self.req = self.httpModule.request(reqOptions)
  } catch (err) {
    self.emit('error', err)
    return
  }

  if (self.timing) {
    self.startTime = startTime
    self.startTimeNow = startTimeNow

    // Timing values will all be relative to startTime (by comparing to startTimeNow
    // so we have an accurate clock)
    self.timings = {}
  }

  var timeout
  if (self.timeout && !self.timeoutTimer) {
    if (self.timeout < 0) {
      timeout = 0
    } else if (typeof self.timeout === 'number' && isFinite(self.timeout)) {
      timeout = self.timeout
    }
  }

  self.req.on('response', self.onRequestResponse.bind(self))
  self.req.on('error', self.onRequestError.bind(self))
  self.req.on('drain', function () {
    self.emit('drain')
  })

  self.req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    // `._connecting` was the old property which was made public in node v6.1.0
    var isConnecting = socket._connecting || socket.connecting
    if (self.timing) {
      self.timings.socket = now() - self.startTimeNow

      if (isConnecting) {
        var onLookupTiming = function () {
          self.timings.lookup = now() - self.startTimeNow
        }

        var onConnectTiming = function () {
          self.timings.connect = now() - self.startTimeNow
        }

        socket.once('lookup', onLookupTiming)
        socket.once('connect', onConnectTiming)

        // clean up timing event listeners if needed on error
        self.req.once('error', function () {
          socket.removeListener('lookup', onLookupTiming)
          socket.removeListener('connect', onConnectTiming)
        })
      }
    }

    var setReqTimeout = function () {
      // This timeout sets the amount of time to wait *between* bytes sent
      // from the server once connected.
      //
      // In particular, it's useful for erroring if the server fails to send
      // data halfway through streaming a response.
      self.req.setTimeout(timeout, function () {
        if (self.req) {
          self.abort()
          var e = new Error('ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')
          e.code = 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'
          e.connect = false
          self.emit('error', e)
        }
      })
    }
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      // Only start the connection timer if we're actually connecting a new
      // socket, otherwise if we're already connected (because this is a
      // keep-alive connection) do not bother. This is important since we won't
      // get a 'connect' event for an already connected socket.
      if (isConnecting) {
        var onReqSockConnect = function () {
          socket.removeListener('connect', onReqSockConnect)
          clearTimeout(self.timeoutTimer)
          self.timeoutTimer = null
          setReqTimeout()
        }

        socket.on('connect', onReqSockConnect)

        self.req.on('error', function (err) { // eslint-disable-line handle-callback-err
          socket.removeListener('connect', onReqSockConnect)
        })

        // Set a timeout in memory - this block will throw if the server takes more
        // than `timeout` to write the HTTP status and headers (corresponding to
        // the on('response') event on the client). NB: this measures wall-clock
        // time, not the time between bytes sent by the server.
        self.timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          socket.removeListener('connect', onReqSockConnect)
          self.abort()
          var e = new Error('ETIMEDOUT')
          e.code = 'ETIMEDOUT'
          e.connect = true
          self.emit('error', e)
        }, timeout)
      } else {
        // We're already connected
        setReqTimeout()
      }
    }
    self.emit('socket', socket)
  })

  self.emit('request', self.req)
}
```

I can't get the HTTP request sent to fetch the image source. Thus I can't get the img.onload handler to be called.

anyone could help me to explain this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't find a way to send a request successfully for loading image.

My solution is: mock the HTMLImageElement's prototype in my test code:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'naturalWidth', { get: () => 120 });
Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'complete', { get: () => true });
```

Thus I don't need to get the real image any more and meanwhile I can finish my test case successfully.